# Sorting an array and indexOf() runtime

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Is it safe to assume that `array.indexOf()` does a linear search from the beginning of the array?

So if I often search for the biggest value, will sorting the array before calling `indexOf` make it run even faster?

Notes:

I want to sort only once and search many times.

"biggest value" is actually the most popular search key which is a string.

Comment: If you're sorting it, you shouldn't use `indexOf` but binary search

Comment: Well...sorting the array takes more than linear time...but if you sort once and search a few times that might make sense...then again you should be using something like a max heap if you need just the max...or a binary search tree if you need to find different values.

Comment: Well what I call "max" is actually the most popular search key which is a string, and yes I want to sort only once. @JCOC611

Comment: you could use a hash table, or a map.

Comment: Is your application really so well optimized and sufficiently intensive that this level of optimization is needed? If not, do whatever is easier to read and maintain, then troubleshoot performance issues when they happen.

Comment: How exactly do you search for biggest value using indexOf?

Comment: Yes I need every little bit of optimisation, it runs on mobile and with huge 3D models. @MichaelL.

Comment: @SalmanA see the notes.

Comment: performance-wise, have you tried [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)? it [seems to perform better](https://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-lastindexof/16) (in some cases) than `indexOf()`... just an idea

Comment: @ZathrusWriter http://i.imgur.com/K7Z4uyH.png

Comment: @kuhaku ok, if that's your target browser/platform, then indexOf() definitelly isn't faster :D ... I was looking at the previous test results: http://imgur.com/a/wuzIk

Comment: Interesting, I'll test it on Safari then. @ZathrusWriter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indexOf is starting from the first to the last. Sorting it before asking the first entry afterwards makes a difference in performance depending in the performance of sorting algorithm. Normally O(N log N) in quicksort to O(n) in linear search. I would suggest you to make a simple test for it with random value count and see how performance behave.

Of course it depends on your DataObject:
ArrayList:

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Perhaps a TreeSet can also help you till its ordered all the time.

At the end i would say:"Depends on your data-container and how the ordering or search is implemented and where the performance in the whole process is needed".

As a comment say with pure arrays you can make binarySearch which has the same performance impact of quicksort.

So at the end its not only a question of the performance of algorithm but also at what time you need the performance in the process. For example if you have lots of time by adding values and no time by getting the value you need, a sorted structure can improve it very well, like Tree-Collections. If you need more performance by adding things its perhaps the other way around.